# Skip processing .xls to Google Sheets script if the file already exists in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am currently using this code to automatically convert all uploaded .xls files in Google Drive to Google Sheets.

```
function importXLS(){
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains ".xls"');
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var xFile = files.next();
    var name = xFile.getName();
    if (name.indexOf('.xls')>-1){
      var ID = xFile.getId();
      var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
      var newFile = { title : name,
                     key : ID,
                     'parents':[{"id":"12FcKokB-ppW7rSBtAIG96uoBOJtTlNDT"}]
                    }
      file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {
        convert: true
      });
    }
  }
}
```

It works perfectly, but fails if there is already a file in the output folder with the same name. Even though I never technically get to see this error below (since it runs on a schedule and not fired manually like in the screenshot), I would prefer to simply skip the conversion process if the file already exists.

[image]

If possible, I would also like to avoid overwriting it each time, as I feel that would be a waste of processing time. How would I edit this code to say that if the file name already exists in that folder, skip the entire code completely?

Thanks!

Comment: You can make another if statement checking the output folder, compare the current file name and the existing file in the folder. You can try the suggested answers in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685232/google-script-test-for-file-existance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you can try:

1. Get the files names that are already in the destination folder and check if the file exists before you try copying.
2. Wrap the section of your code that does the copying in a `try..catch` statement.

Both of these should work independently, but using the `try..catch` statement will catch *all* errors, so it would be best to combine them. (You can review the [error logs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) in the Developer Console.) Doing this you'll be able to skip files that have the same name as those already in your destination folder and any other error that might come up will not terminate your script from completing.

```
function importXLS(){
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains ".xls"');
  var destinationFolderId = "12FcKokB-ppW7rSBtAIG96uoBOJtTlNDT";
  var existingFileNames = getFilesInFolder(destinationFolderId);
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var xFile = files.next();
    var name = xFile.getName();
    try {
      if (!existingFileNames[name] && (name.indexOf('.xls')>-1)) {
        var ID = xFile.getId();
        var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
        var newFile = { title : name,
                       key : ID,
                       'parents':[{"id": destinationFolderId}]
                      }
        file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {
          convert: true
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error with file " + name + ": " + error);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Get an object of all file names in the specified folder.
 * @param {string} folderId
 * @returns {Object} files - {filename: true}
 */
function getFilesInFolder(folderId) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();
  var files = {};
  while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
    var file = filesIterator.next();
    files[file.getName()] = true;
  }
  return files;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. You are a legend, do you have a place that I can tip you for your help?

Comment: Haha no worries :)